# How to delete branching TreeItems from a TreeView in javafx?

Tags: recursion, javafx, treeview, erase

How would I implement the method

```
private void wipeTreeViewStructure(TreeItem node)
```

where "node" is a TreeItem which, along with all of its connected TreeItems, gets erased on execution? I tried something along the lines of

```
    private void wipeTreeViewStructure(TreeItem node) {
    for (TreeItem i : node.getChildren()) {
        wipeTreeViewStructure(i);
        i.delete();
    }
}
```

but that has two major flaws:

1. I'm getting an "Incompatible types" error in the "i", which I don't know what to make out of.
2. there is apparently no delete() or any similar method implemented for TreeItem.

With this many unknowns, I thought it would be better to just ask how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your incompatible types error is (I think) because you are using raw types, instead of properly specifying the type of the object in the `TreeItem`. In other words, you should be using

```
TreeItem<Something>
```

instead of just the raw

```
TreeItem
```

The `Something` is whatever you are using as data in your tree. Your IDE should be giving you lots of warnings over this.

You don't need recursion at all here. To remove the tree item, just remove it from its parent's list of child nodes. It will effectively take all its descendents with it. You can do

```
node.getParent().getChildren().remove(node);
```

and that should do everything you need. (If the node might be the root of the tree, then you should check for that first.)

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeViewWithDelete extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeItem<String> treeRoot = new TreeItem<>("Root");
        treeRoot.setExpanded(true);

        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>(treeRoot);
        tree.getSelectionModel().select(treeRoot);

        Button delete = new Button("Delete");


        delete.setOnAction(e -> {
            TreeItem<String> selected = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            selected.getParent().getChildren().remove(selected);
        });


        delete.disableProperty().bind(tree.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull()
                .or(tree.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isEqualTo(treeRoot)));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button add = new Button("Add");
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> addAction = e -> {
            TreeItem<String> selected = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (selected == null) {
                selected = treeRoot ;
            }
            String text = textField.getText();
            if (text.isEmpty()) {
                text = "New Item";
            }
            TreeItem<String> newItem = new TreeItem<>(text);
            selected.getChildren().add(newItem);
            newItem.setExpanded(true);
            tree.getSelectionModel().select(newItem);
        };
        textField.setOnAction(addAction);
        add.setOnAction(addAction);

        HBox controls = new HBox(5, textField, add, delete);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tree, null, null, controls, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, this works, but could you please explain the exact reasoning behind the line "selected.getParent().getChildren().remove(selected);"? Why not just "remove(selected)", wouldn't that do the same thing?

Comment: What are you intending to call `remove(selected)` on? (I.e. which `remove` method are you referring to?)

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now, you don't "delete" it directly somehow, you get its parent node's children list and remove it from there, did I get it right? And do selected's connected nodes get deleted too; does Java recognize them as being up for garbage collection?

Comment: Yes, I think you understand that. As for the selected's child nodes, if selected is no longer part of the tree structure, then its child nodes are not part of the tree structure (where would they be in the tree?). The usual rules for garbage collection apply: if there is no path to the tree items via references then they are eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Put another way, a node is in a tree if it is either the root of the tree, or it is in the child list of a node that is in the tree (that's just what a "tree" means). So you remove a node from a tree by removing it from the child list it belongs to (the child list of its parent). Once it is no longer an element of the tree, its child nodes are no longer elements of the tree, by definition, and their child nodes are no longer elements of the tree, etc.